# Error while sourcing shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

In order to complete an installation, I need to source the following .sh file:

```
function addvar () {
local tmp="${!1}" ;
tmp="${tmp//:${2}:/:}" ; tmp="${tmp/#${2}:/}" ; tmp="${tmp/%:${2}/}" ;
export $1="${2}:${tmp}" ;
} 

if [ -z "${PATH}" ]; then 
PATH=/share/MontePython/plc-2.0/bin
export PATH
else
addvar PATH /share/MontePython/plc-2.0/bin
fi
if [ -z "${PYTHONPATH}" ]; then 
PYTHONPATH=/share/MontePython/plc-2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages
export PYTHONPATH
else
addvar PYTHONPATH /share/MontePython/plc-2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages
fi
if [ -z "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/share/apps/intel/l_ics_2015.1.133/composer_xe_2015.1.133/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
addvar LD_LIBRARY_PATH /share/apps/intel/l_ics_2015.1.133/composer_xe_2015.1.133/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64
fi
if [ -z "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/share/apps/intel/l_ics_2015.1.133/composer_xe_2015.1.133/compiler/lib/intel64/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
addvar LD_LIBRARY_PATH /share/apps/intel/l_ics_2015.1.133/composer_xe_2015.1.133/compiler/lib/intel64/
fi
if [ -z "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/share/apps/intel/l_ics_2015.1.133/composer_xe_2015.1.133/compiler/lib/intel64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
addvar LD_LIBRARY_PATH /share/apps/intel/l_ics_2015.1.133/composer_xe_2015.1.133/compiler/lib/intel64
fi
if [ -z "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
addvar LD_LIBRARY_PATH /lib64
fi
if [ -z "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
addvar LD_LIBRARY_PATH /lib
fi
if [ -z "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/share/apps/intel/l_ics_2015.1.133/composer_xe_2015.1.133/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
addvar LD_LIBRARY_PATH /share/apps/intel/l_ics_2015.1.133/composer_xe_2015.1.133/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64/
fi
if [ -z "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/share/MontePython/plc-2.0/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
addvar LD_LIBRARY_PATH /share/MontePython/plc-2.0/lib
fi
CLIK_PATH=/share/MontePython/plc-2.0
export CLIK_PATH

CLIK_DATA=/share/MontePython/plc-2.0/share/clik
export CLIK_DATA

CLIK_PLUGIN=rel2015
export CLIK_PLUGIN
```

but when I source it, I get the following error:

```
() not correctly positioned
```

Any idea why?
The curious thing is that this error is happening when I operate on a cluster, while I don't have it on my PC.

EDIT:

The output of `lsb_release -a`   is:

```
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
Release:    6.9
Codename:   Final
```

The output of `echo $0` is `-tcsh`.

Comment: What linux distro do you use? What type of cluster? I can source it without any issues on both CentOS 6.x & 7.x, also on Promox (but no clustering)

Comment: Are you getting that error with `bash` or `sh`? You tagged both of them, but they aren't the same

Comment: @BogdanStoica I edited the post to answer the questions

Comment: Why would you want to source this monstrosity?  At the very least refactor it to put the `test -z`'s in the function addvar.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I have no choice, it does not depend on me, I have to source it. How, correctly?

Comment: The only thing this script is doing is adding data to PATH, PYTHONPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, CLIK_PATH, CLIK_DATA, and CLIK_PLUGIN.  Just make the necessary assignments.  Since you're using tcsh, you'll need to the appropriate syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're using a different shell (tcsh) rather than sh or bash. Most probably you have to adapt your source code to make it load using tcsh. Under sh/bash works just fine

```
root@pve1:~# echo $0
-bash
```

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`, your script is syntactically correct. But if you use `sh`, then there are a few errors. Check the [`shellcheck`](https://www.shellcheck.net/) output:

```
$ shellcheck script.sh 

In script.sh line 3:
function addvar () {
^-- SC2112: 'function' keyword is non-standard. Delete it.


In script.sh line 4:
local tmp="${!1}" ;
^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, 'local' is undefined.
           ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, indirect expansion is undefined.


In script.sh line 5:
tmp="${tmp//:${2}:/:}" ; tmp="${tmp/#${2}:/}" ; tmp="${tmp/%:${2}/}" ;
     ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, string replacement is undefined.
                              ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, string replacement is undefined.
                                                     ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, string replacement is undefined.
```

In summary:

- `function` keyword is not needed (or even recommended)
- `local` isn't supported in POSIX `sh`
- string replacement `${//}` is not supported in `sh`.

Comment: Should I then force it to be used with bash? If yes, how?

Comment: Since you're sourcing the script, you have to **source it from `bash`**.

Comment: puttin #!/bin/bash at the beginning of the script?

Comment: @johnhenry, that won't help, since he's *sourcing* the script, not *running*. When a script is sourced, its content is evaluated in the current shell.